# Best practice around sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database-design, index-tuning

I have a fairly simple query using **sys.dm_db_missing_index_group_stats** that identifies missing indexes in my SQL Server database. This is pretty commonly used. My question is how do I identify which of these indexes are important and should be created and should I just create them all or are there any other secrets? Anything I specifically should look for in the avg_user_impact or avg_total_user_cost columns?

Answer (score 5):

Kimberly Tripp did a few very good video's on Index Analysis that covered your question extremely well as part of the MCM Readiness videos.

[Indexing Strategies Demo](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sqlserver/gg545005.aspx)
[Indexing Strategies](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sqlserver/gg545006.aspx)
[Index Analysis](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/sqlserver/gg545020.aspx)

Among other things she said DO NOT just create all of them.  Review each one and compare it to your existing indexes, review it's cost etc.  I highly recommend them and best of all they are free!